# Telerik reporting show selected parameter value

Tags: telerik, telerik-reporting

I am new to telerik reporting using Q3 2014.
While designing the report in designer I want to show the parameter value (in my case 'Date') that is used to filter the records.
I am using SQL Datasource with Stored Procedure. Is there a way to accomplish this in designer view?

Answer (score 0):

when you say you want to display the date parameter used to filter, do you mean in a label on the report? This can be done by setting your label value to:

```
=Parameters.ParameterNameHere.Value
```

with formatting it is:

```
=Parameter.ParameterNameHere.Value.ToString('dd.MM.yyyy')
```